# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError when using STI models in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I made the following models:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UrgentRequest < Request
  has_one:note
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :request_id,.... 
  belongs_to :urgent_request, :foreign_key=>'request_id', :class_name=>'Request'
end
```

In my controller I've set up an action to create an `UrgentRequest` object:

```
def new_scheduled_request
  @request = UrgentRequest.new
  @request.build_note #<-- getting error here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @request }
  end
end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in RequestsController#new_urgent_request
unknown attribute: urgent_request_id
```

The line number is where I'm invoking the `build_note` call. The form on the page is supposed to be a nested form. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Uh never mind I found out the issue. Apparently I had to explicitly mention in the UrgentRequests model in the has_one:note association the foreign key and class name parameters. Works fine now!